# Using Bootstrap 4 without JQuery in Angular 9 project

Tags: jquery, angular

I am trying to remove all JQuery dependencies & usages in my Angular project, which are caused by usage of Bootstrap 4. I removed the dropdown and all `data-***` usages.
But once I uninstalled JQuery and popper.js, I see the TypeError message `Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery. jQuery must be included before Bootstrap's JavaScript.` in my web console. I am wondering if there are other dependencies `data-***` or the Bootstrap dropdown or collapse.. Are Bootstrap button classes depending on JQuery too?

Comment: Bootstrap 4.x requires jQuery. If you want to remove jQuery then check Bootstrap 5.

Comment: Hi Robert, does it mean I have to install jQuery for Bootstrap 4 no matter if I need JQuery or not?

Comment: You need jQuery if you use `bootstrap.js` in your Angular app. If you use bootstrap only for style (css only) then no need for jQuery. But `data-toggle` etc will not work.

Comment: How can I find in the codebase where exactly Bootstrap.js is used?

Comment: Check your `angular.json` file and look for `scripts` property. If `bootstrap.js` or `bootstrap.min.js` is there then remove it. If that section is empty then check `index.html` and check the `<head>` section for bootstrap.

Comment: wow that is the approach I needed! Thank you so much! If you want, you can post it as an answer, I will confirm the correct solution :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The console error depends on how you have imported/installed bootstrap.

If it was included in via npm then you need to run `npm uninstall bootstrap`.
Next, go the angular.json file and check `ctrl + f` for any bootstrap includes, specially here:

```
        "scripts": [
          "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
          "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        ]
```

Once you remove all imports of bootstrap, restart the app: `ng serve`.

If you're still getting an error then it's most probably some file that's trying to use JQuery other than Bootstrap code.

Answer (score 2):

To remove bootstrap JS dependency:

Check your `angular.json` file and look for `scripts` property.
You should see something like this:

```
        "scripts": [
          "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
          "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        ]
```

If `bootstrap.js` or `bootstrap.min.js` is there then remove it.

If that section is empty then check `index.html` and check the `<head>` section for bootstrap. Something like this:

```
<link href="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

Same here. Remove bootstrap and jquery `<script src=...` lines.

To be on safe side. Restart your angular dev server then `ng serve`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ng-bootstrap` `npm package` which is designed to **eliminate the need for jquery**,

If you are using `Angular 10` and above, it will be installed directly in the Module.ts.

Otherwise, simply add it like this

```
import {NgbPaginationModule, NgbAlertModule} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

@NgModule({
  imports: [NgbPaginationModule, NgbAlertModule],
})
export class YourAppModule {
}
```

Comment: Hi, I am aware of this, I am already trying to use ng-bootstrap. Nevertheless, there is obviously Bootstrap components using JQuery in the codebase already :/ It's very hard for me to figure out how to find these components..